# Custom woocommerce coupon fields in custom place

Tags: woocommerce, checkout

I created a custom checkout page.

I wanted to put the coupon code anywhere and it worked.

Unfortunately after clicking on the "apply coupon" button, instead of validating the coupon and adding it to the order, the system responds as per clicking the "order and pay" button Code used in **form-checkout.php**:

```
<?php do_action('woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', $checkout); ?>

<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div class="checkout-form-container">
            <?php if ( sizeof( $checkout->checkout_fields ) > 0 ) : ?>
                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details' ); ?>

                <div class="col2-set" id="customer_details">
                    <div class="col-1">
                        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_billing' ); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details'); ?>

                <p class="form-row form-row-first">
                    <label for="coupon_code">Coupon?</label>
                    <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="custom-coupon-code-input input-text" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Wprowadż kod', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" id="coupon_code" value="" />
                </p>

                <p class="form-row form-row-last">
                                           <input type="submit"button class="button custom-apply-coupon-btn">
                        <?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                    </button>
                </p>

            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your checkout page HTML. You are actually putting your coupon form inside checkout form. HTML forms doesn't support nested forms.

Put the form outside of checkout form. If you really need to show them there then take those values by javascript with the click of 'Apply Coupon' button and do the validation. But A form tag inside another form is not the correct way.

The submit button is submitting parent form also. That's why you are getting that.

Answer (score 0):

I know where is the problem. Everything works perfectly on woo 2.6.8 but after update to min 3.0.4 its crash as I described above.